# PhoneGap + Angular + IOS = ng-show flashes the content on the screen

Tags: angularjs, cordova

When accessing my website built with AngularJS 1.2.0rc1 via the InAppBrowser within PhoneGap 2.7.0 on IOS, the contents of an ng-show flicker on the screen.

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="manualEntryForm" class="form-inline">
  <div ng-show="showErrors && !manualEntryForm.$valid" class="errorMsg ng-hide">
    One or more of the following fields are required:
    <span ng-show="manualEntryForm.month.$error.required || manualEntryForm.day.$error.required || manualEntryForm.year.$error.required" class="ng-hide">Date needs to be present</span>
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

It doesn't matter if I default `showErrors` to false or test it more rigorously (`showErrors === true`), that block of error content will display and also show the actual error message associated (`Date needs to be present`).

I'm stumped as to how to address this. Should we not be using the Angular Form Validation within that ng-show? Why is it only causing an issue on IOS/Phonegap InAppBrowser?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. ng-cloak didn't solve the problem, so what solved the issue for me was to add

```
class="ng-hide"
```

to each element with the ng-show attribute, and now it doesn't flash the content on ios.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-cloak` to hide the element during compilation:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak

It might be showing up before the AngularJS compiler has had time to run. And it might only be showing in iOS/Phonegap because the webkit browser in UIWebView is nowhere near as fast as Mobile Safari, let alone a desktop browser.

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround, I ended up removing ng-show, and instead adding an ng-class="{hidden: myCondition}", then defining .hidden { display: none; } in CSS. This removed the flashing.